# How do I make a foreign key appear as its own form instead of a dropdown menu?

Tags: django, inline-formset

I'm trying to create a formset for a list of movies like so:

```
class MovieList(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie)

class Movie(models.Model):
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

MovieListFormSet = inlineformset_factory(User, MovieList)
movielist_formset = MovieListFormSet(instance=currentUser)
```

Right now "Movie" is appearing as a dropdown menu. However, I'd like it so that "Movie" appears as a blank textbox for 'Movie.name', and a dropdown menu for 'Movie.genre'.  The user can enter in the movie name in the textbox and select the genre, and if that movie already exists, MovieList.movie references the existing table row, otherwise a new MovieList row is created and MovieList.movie references the new table row.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want more complex logic, why not to create a new formset from scratch. It shouldn't be much code.

Comment: I'd be fine with doing that, but I'm having trouble finding where to start as I'm relatively new to Django.  Do you know of any examples you can point me to?  I can't find anywhere where others are replacing their Foreign Key dropdown menus with a subform, though I imagine I can't be the first person to try this.